# How can I strip html tags except some of them?

Tags: php, regex, string, html

I need to remove all html codes from a php string except:

```
<p>
<em>
<small>
```

You know, strip_tags() function is good, but it strips all html tags, how can I tell it remove all html except those tags above?

Comment: @Jan OP needs to include such information in the question itself. Comments are just temporary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your comment, you want to remove HTML elements only if they have some class or attribute. You'll need to build up a DOM then:

```
<?php

$data = <<<DATA
<div>
    <p>These line shall stay</p>
    <p class="myclass">Remove this one</p>
    <p><a href="#somewhere">I will be deleted as well</a></p>
    <p>But keep this</p>
</div>
DATA;

$dom = new DOMDOcument();
$dom->loadHTML($data, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED); 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$elements_to_be_removed = $xpath->query("//*[count(@*)>0]");
foreach ($elements_to_be_removed as $element) {
    $element->parentNode->removeChild($element);
}

// just to check
echo $dom->saveHTML();
?>
```

To change which elements shall be removed, you'll need to change the query, ie to remove **all** elements with the class `myclass`, it must read `"//*[class='myclass']"`.

Comment: Ok just one thing, your approach works just for class attribute, can you please develop your approach for all attributes?

Comment: @MartinAJ: Maybe you'd better go for some reading on xpath. Surely I could do this for you here but a) you'd need to transfer some of your honorar and b) where's the joy for you then?

Comment: Seems you love your job *(programming)* ..! ok just one thing, why there is some new tags in the [result](https://3v4l.org/Etua8)? I mean `<!DOCTYPE ... <html><body>`

Comment: good for you and thank you for the edition version of your answer. but still `<html>` and `<body>` tags are there .. Look, all I'm trying to do is striping html tags that have class *(or whatever)* attribute from the string (because I want to keep my website UI safe against what user enters) .. So I need to get that string in pure form .. is that possible?

Comment: I guess we can wrap it into a element like `$dom->loadHTML("<div id="foo">$data</div>"); ` and then fetch it like this `$dom->saveHtml($dom->getElementById("foo"));` .. hum? what you think?

Comment: @MartinAJ: Look into the updated answer - first it removes all elements which has at least one attribute and second it outputs only a portion of the DOM.

Comment: Oh .. I found a great thing .. [`$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED);`](http://php.net/manual/en/libxml.constants.php#constant.libxml-html-noimplied) .. I guess you want to edit your answer and make it perfect `:-)`

Answer (score 6):

> You should check out the manual: [Example #1 strip_tags() example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php#refsect1-function.strip-tags-examples)
>
> Syntax: **strip_tags** ( Your-string, Allowable-Tags )

If you pass the second parameter, these tags will not be stripped.

```
strip_tags($string, '<p><em><small>');
```

Comment: This is good thank you, upvote. Just I want to remove tags that have attribute like this <p class="myclass">test</p>

Comment: @MartinAJ: You'll need to build up a DOM then and edit your original question to reflect all your requirements.